# Can a DLL be used with other Programming Languages?

Tags: java, c++, .net, dll

What programming language can support same dll?

I just bought a product bundled with 3 api: JAVA, .NET, C++

In each api folder, I found dll files on .Net and C++ folder while jar file on java folder. My question is, can i integrate dll on different languages? I already tried implementing a dll in java using jni and it worked. I read that dll supports multi language program but why is that different dll were used with .net and c++?

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No. DLL is PL specific. In visual studio you have COM objects which can be used in other VS based PLs. You can use sockets with  client and server topology to talk from one program to another program.

Comment: From what I know, a lot of language (like ruby, python, java, scala, php, lua ...) can use those dll files, you need to create a wrapper/link object for that language, I think the introductory of that language should have some document for this issue

Comment: Please have a look at my answer @seccpur.

Comment: @seccpur: The way you call a DLL written in another language varies from language to language - but it is *very* common to be able to do so.  There is nothing particularly magical about COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be perfectly possible to call the C++ DLL from C# (or other .Net language), but it would be a matter of writing P/Invoke code to do so (and this is hard).

As a matter of convenience, the authors of the API have written a native C# wrapper for you which you can use much as you would use any other C# class.

(The above assumes that the "real" DLL is the C++ one - it could actually be the C# one, and the C++ DLL is a wrapper written in C++/CLI.  Doesn't actually much change the logic.)

Similarly writing JNI interfaces is tedious and fiddly - much better to do it once (right), rather than answer all the support calls "How do I..."

Comment: JNA is pretty simple and can call DLL and SO.

Comment: So meaning, I can still write a program even the product's sdk only packaged a, for example a c++ sample codes, using its dll? i'll reverse a question, are there programming language who can't call a dll?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have never met a foreign language interface I would describe as "simple".  Certainly not as simple as a native call.

Comment: @MartinBonner JNA is far simpler (but also slower) than JNI. You create an interface in Java and call a function to bind it to a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia as of 15th of November 2016,

> Dynamic-link library (or DLL) is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows and OS/2 operating systems. These libraries usually have the file extension DLL, OCX (for libraries containing ActiveX controls), or DRV (for legacy system drivers). The file formats for DLLs are the same as for Windows EXE files – that is, Portable Executable (PE) for 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and New Executable (NE) for 16-bit Windows. As with EXEs, DLLs can contain code, data, and resources, in any combination.

This means that you can store different things including code into a DLL. A DLL is loaded at runtime. You can load DLLs according to a language's supported features.

You can do this in the following ways:-

- In Java via the JNI interface.
- In [C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms235636.aspx)
- In any other language that supports calling DLLs.

Another point to be noted is that the DLL must be compiled for the operating system you will be calling it on before hand. Different operating systems have different file extensions / concepts for DLLs as an analogy.
For example, the following workflow is valid,
**Compile DLL in C++** -> **Store in Disk** -> **Call your DLL from any other language like C# / C++/ Java**

Comment: What if i'm the technical engineer, and the client asked me"does the product is applicable with *PL*", is it safe to say "yes" as long as it has dll?

Comment: As long as the conditions are met(You have a way to import and use DLLs in your programming language and the DLL is compiled for the right OS) you're mostly fine. The only real way to be sure is to try compiling an application that uses functions / code given in the DLL.